# definition of UINT_MAX macro

Tags: c++, macros, numeric-limits

I would like to know if there is a particular reason to define the macro `UINT_MAX` as `(2147483647 * 2U + 1U)`  and not directly its true value `(4294967295U)` in the `climits` header file.

Thank you all.

Comment: The library implementors would know this best.

Comment: It could be a bug workaround for an early bug in the lexer.  If it tokenized the number and the postfix separately then it could easily have suffered from an overflow.  It of course helps when you document in what kind of toolchain you found this back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as the compiled code is concerned, there would be no difference, because the compiler would evaluate both constant expressions to produce the same value at compile time.

Defining `UINT_MAX` in terms of `INT_MAX` lets you reuse a constant that you have already defined:

```
#define UINT_MAX (INT_MAX * 2U + 1U)
```

In fact, this is very much what [clang's header does](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/limits_8h_source.html), reusing an internal constant `__INT_MAX__` for both `INT_MAX` and `UINT_MAX`:

```
#define INT_MAX   __INT_MAX__
#define UINT_MAX  (__INT_MAX__  *2U +1U)
```